# How to keep columns labels when numeric convert to character

Tags: r

```
a<- data.frame(sex=c(1,1,2,2,1,1),bq=factor(c(1,2,1,2,2,2)))
library(Hmisc)
label(a$sex)<-"gender"
label(a$bq)<-"xxx"
str(a) 

b<-data.frame(lapply(a, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(b)
```

When I covert dataframe a columns to character,the columns labels disappeared.My dataframe have many columns.Here as an example only two columns. How to keep columns labels when numeric convert to character? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels are not a commonly used R feature. Unfortunately, you will have to do it yourself:

```
b <- data.frame(lapply(a, function(x) { y <- as.character(x); label(y) <- label(x); y }), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Or just label after conversion. :)